# Multi-dimensional loop assistance

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

Trying to check possible combos in this sort of array:

`[ ["X","X","X"], ["","",""], ["","",""] ]`

Combos include:
`tic tac toe logic`

So, these are `true`:

`[ ["X","",""], ["","X",""], ["","","X"] ]`

`[ ["","","X"], ["","X",""], ["X","",""] ]`

`[ ["","X",""], ["","X",""], ["","X",""] ]`

So far, I have it working as long as my `array[0][0]` is the one of the selected choices, but I feel I'm moving towards a *stack* of `code`.

```
function testWin(){
    var cs=b.length, ph=0, pv=0, pd=0;
    for(var i=0;i<cs;i++){
        if(b[0][i]==="X"){ ph++; }
        if(b[i][0]==="X"){ pv++; }
        if(b[i][i]==="X"){ pd++; }
    }
    if(ph===cs || pv===cs || pd===cs){ alert("YOU WIN!"); }
}
```

## Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/z4XLj/

1. Been trying another `for loop` to no success to identify `0`
2. Tried a `while loop`, but it crashed and I don't think that is the most effective anyway.
3. Need to find if...

   - ANY `array[i][this]` contains nothing but `X`
   - ANY `array[this][i]` contains nothing but `X`

Comment: **NO REASON TO BOLD EVERYTHING**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I now this looks like black magic, but here you have:

```
function testWin(){
    var cs = b.length, I = [], J = [], d = [0, 0];
    for(var i=0; i<cs; i++){
       for(var j=0; j<cs; j++){
           if(b[i][j] != 'X') continue;
           I[i] = (I[i] || 0) + 1;
           J[j] = (J[j] || 0) + 1;
           if(i == j) d[0]++;  //Diagonal \
           if(i == cs-j-1) d[1]++;  //Diagonal /
       }
    }
    if(d.concat(I).concat(J).indexOf(cs) >=0) alert("You win");
}
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/edgarinvillegas/z4XLj/3/

It considers any horizontal, vertical or diagonal victory for board of any size

:O It works! :)

Cheers, from La Paz, Bolivia

Answer (score 0):

```
function testWin() {
    var xCount;
    var rowsCount = b.length;
    // First check rows
    for (var row = 0; row < rowsCount; row++) {
        xCount = 0;
        colsCount = b[row].length;
        for (var col = 0; col < colsCount; col++) {
            if (b[row][col] == "X") {
                xCount++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (xCount == colsCount) {
            alert ("YOU WIN!");
            return true;
        }
    }
    // Now check columns -- just invert the above nested loops
    colsCount = b[0].length;
    for (var col = 0; col < colsCount; col++) {
        xCount = 0;
        for (var row = 0; row < rowsCount; row++) {
            if (b[row][col] == "X") {
                xCount++;
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (xCount == rowsCount) {
            alert ("YOU WIN!");
            return true;
        }
    }
    // Check diagonals
    if (b[1][1] == "X" && 
        ((b[0][0] == "X" && b[2][2] == "X") || (b[0][2] == "X" && b[2][0] == "X"))) {
        alert ("YOU WIN!");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: So, functionality improves, but it is still hard coded for `2` as an `index`. Lemme play with it. Thank you :-)

Comment: There's probably something in underscore.js, but nothing in native Javascript.

Comment: Thank you :-) Going to eventually golf this code, so trying to find minimalist ways to achieve simple functions.

Comment: So go with Edgar's answer -- I don't think you could get much more minimalistic.

Comment: I'm working on it :-) I found an even more mimalistic solution, but having trouble debugging the diagonals. I'll post my code this evening on it.